# What is a phoenix in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, unearthed-arcana

In the [Unearthed Arcana: Sorcerer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf), the sorcerous origin "Phoenix Sorcery" is introduced. I didn't find an entry for the phoenix in the Monster Manual or Volo's Guide; I heard there is a mention of that creature in the DMG, but couldn't find it. So, where is this creature mentioned exactly? (To be clear: I know what a phoenix, as a fabled creature, is, I just am not sure what a phoenix is in D&D 5e).

Comment: I was about to ask why you'd expect it to be statted anywhere or for it to be specified, but then I remembered the [gorgons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Phoenix is mentioned in *Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop* under *Creating a Monster*.  It is an example for **Modifying a Monster**:

> Need a fiery phoenix? [...]

(DMG, p.273)

I don't know how much I am allowed to quote, but this should be enough to answer your question.

---

With the release of **Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes** comes a stat block for the [Phoenix](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/phoenix) (MToF, p. 199).

It is now a so called *Elder Elemental*, and is a legendary creature which consists entirely of fire and has the iconic *Fiery Death and Rebirth* ability.

Comment: @JosephDoob you should be more disappointed by the *content* of that entry: phoenixes now have nothing to do with the cycle of death and rebirth (viz.  they are not reborn from their ashes when slain, which is sort of the whole point of the phoenix...)

Answer (score 12):

**The phoenix in 5e is a a fiery bird, similar to the giant eagle or roc, with
immunity to fire, that can deal fire damage with its attacks.**

This is taken from pg 273 of the DMG under:

> MODIFYING A MONSTER
>
> Need a fiery phoenix? Take the giant eagle or roc, give it immunity to fire, and allow it to deal fire damage with its attacks.

**Additional details:**

As I understand it, it was originally included in the Monster Manual, but was cut for space.  I think I heard this on Dragon Talk or the Tome Show, but I can't find that reference right now, so don't hold me to that.

It is now officially published in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, on pg. 199.